# Trying to avoid ambiguity in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, ambiguity

I need to sync filters in many projects, but yet i don't know the right approach. In fact, i'm using Cross Filter Both Direction to do this, but i have been told that this is can create a ambiguity problem (when complex models arise).I just whatched a video on YT that explains this problem and give a "simple" solution, but i'm not getting the same result. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3m7qzsVJqQ&ab_channel=SQLBI)

Just to illustrate the problem:

[image]

When a filter with Customer's name is selected, i want to create another filter to the product table with only the colors that were purchased by that customer. With single direction on the relation Sales x Product, this doesn't happens, but if i change the relation to both direction, we get what we want.

The solution suggested was to keep single direction and add a filter (visual level) on color's filter, saying that i want just the Sales table rows where Date(any column) is not blank. But when i did this, the color's filter yet doesn't "interact" with customer's filter.

Where is the problem ?

[image]

[image]